# Echo Record With MAX Value in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to echo record that has a MAX Value in php,So how i do that?

I have table like this:

```
id|value
1 | 3
2 | 1
```

What i've tried so far is use query `SELECT MAX(value) FROM user`

but it just echo max user,so how i can show record with id that have MAX value in Codeigniter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only one row with actual data you should use another appoach with sorting and limit. See code below:

```
SELECT * FROM user order by value desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a name to the column as below and you can echo val

```
SELECT MAX(value) val FROM user
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE value = (SELECT MAX(value) FROM user)
```

This will you the maximum `value` and the corresponding `id`